# Adding fixed wing CFII SEL to helicopter CFII rating

Tags: helicopter, fixed-wing

I am a CFII, and have just been asked to assist a Helicopter pilot who has FIH (CFFII-Helicopter) and a Commercial fixed wing (SEL) certificates to obtain a CFII SEL rating.

My research to date indicates to me that he needs the following:

- Spin training
- Sufficient instruction to be able to teach required skills from the right seat of a single-engine airplane
- Knowledge test-- AIF (short instrument add-on for FIH to CFII)

Does he also need to take the AFA knowledge test (add-on test for FRH to CFI)?

Comment: So, basically, he just wants to add on an airplane single engine and instrument airplane ratings onto his flight instructor certificate? Correct?